# Power series with a given value a = 1

Tags: calculus

Find a power series representation for *f(x)* at the given value of *a*.

$$g(x) = \frac{1}{2+x} ; a=1$$

I could do this problem if a=0, but how does this change when a=1 instead?

Comment: Do you know about Taylor series?

Comment: @FelipeJacop: yeah

Comment: @user136088 How do you find a power series for $f(x)$ when you've given $g(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$g(x) = \frac{1}{2+x} ; a=1\\
\implies g(1)=\frac{1}{3}\\
\implies g^{'}(1)=\left(\frac{-1}{(2+1)^2}\right)=\frac{-1}{9}\\
\implies g^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(2+x)^{n+1}}\\
\implies g^{(n)}(1)=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{3^{n+1}}$$
Thus,
$$g(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{g^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(x-1)^n\text{ about $1$.}\\
\implies g(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}}(x-1)^n\text{ about $1$.}$$
This converges for $$\{x||1-x|<3\}$$
So, the radius of convergence is $3$.

Comment: What would the radius of convergence be for this question?

Comment: @user136088 What do you think?

Comment: would the radius be 1?

Comment: @user136088 No. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $g(x) = \frac{1}{2+x}$ and you want to make the expansion at $a$, you could rewrite $$g(x) = \frac{1}{(2+a)+(x-a)}=\frac{1}{2+a} \times \frac{1}{1+\frac{x-a}{2+a}}$$  and now set $y=\frac{x-a}{2+a}$

So, $$g(x) =\frac{1}{2+a} \times\frac{1}{1+y}$$ Expand $ \frac{1}{1+y}$ around $y=0$ and replace later $y$ by $\frac{x-a}{2+a}$. Later, if you wish, replace $a$ by the number you want ($1$ in your case).